# Is it possible to define rules with nested object in CASL

Tags: casl

Right now I have 'user' object with nested object named 'author' with id field in it. How can I define rules for that object?

This code doesn't work:

```
can('manage', 'Post', { author: { id: id } });
```

Neither this one (well, it works, but I save rules in localStorage, and saving functions inside of it is not a good idea)

```
can('manage', 'Post', { 'author': function(author) { ... } });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use dot notation:

```js
can('manage', 'Post', { 'author.id': id });
```

You can find more information about query language and common cases to define rules in [CASL docs](https://stalniy.github.io/casl/v4/en/guide/conditions-in-depth)